# Compute everything inside foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I have `foreach` which consist of the list of candidates. I'm trying to compute the percentage inside the foreach then output the result. I don't know the problem, I want the program to compute the first *if statement(talent)*, after going to the next *if statement(distance)*, then continue the computation. The `echo` will display the overall computation of percentage. Please help. Thanks in advance

```
    $counter = 0;
    $status = array();

    foreach($candidate as $c){  
        $queryResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE id = '$c'"); 
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResult);

        if($talent == "good"){
            $status[$counter] = + 0.10;

        }else if($talent == "better"){
            $status[$counter] = + 0.05;
        }

        if($distance == "1200m"){
            $status[$counter] = + 0.10;
        }else if($distance == "1400m"){
            $status[$counter] = + 0.05;
        }
        echo $status[$counter] * 100 . "%<br>";
        $counter ++;

    }//foreach end
```

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Comment: Are `tallent` and `distance` columns in your table? If so, you must take them from `$row`.

Comment: "_go to the first if statement after going to the next if statement_" I'm confused by this.

Comment: Thanks. But I used that for sample only. I'm using mysqli.

Comment: @Takendarkk, compute the first if statement, before going to the next if. Because that code only compute the last if statement

Comment: maybe you want something like: `$counter/mysqli_stmt_num_rows($queryResult)*100` for the percentage count..? and you might want to store this `mysqli_stmt_num_rows($queryResult)` in a variable so that you don't calculate it over and over again..

Comment: @Jack, yes. but I guess my problem is my counter

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉, inside my foreach I need to compute the over all percentage. I guess there's a problem with my counter

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉,  There's nothing wrong with my sql query. My problem is the if statements inside the foreach

Comment: Sorry Everyone. I forgot to include what I did inside the if statement.

Comment: sorry, but, who said that your sql query is wrong..?

Comment: how about changing those `=+` with `+=`, perhaps that is what you want ..? (e.g., `$status[$counter] += 0.10;`)

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 After changing, I got this Notice: Undefined offset:

Comment: @rrr: do you realize the difference between them? Have you tried to find what `+=` means? Why haven't you?

Comment: I got the result I need, but What to do with the Notice: Undefined offset: ?

Comment: try to initialize this before the `foreach` loop.. `$array = array_fill(0,$number_of_candidates, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about changing those `=+` with `+=`, perhaps that is what you want ..? (e.g., `$status[$counter] += 0.10;`)

and try to initialize this before the `foreach` loop..

```
$array = array_fill(0,$number_of_candidates, 0);
```